# Python　LU分解プログラム　ヒルベルト行列

Tags: python

LU分解プログラムでヒルベルト行列を係数とする連立一次方程式を解きたいです。

以下のプログラムでは `invalid literal for int() with base 10` というようなエラーが出てしまいます。
どのように変更したらうまく動くようになりますでしょうか。
いろいろ自分なりに調べて書いたので見当違いかもしれないですがよろしくお願いします。

```
import math
a = int(input("Enter row"))
b = int(input("Enter column"))
def hilmat(a,b):
li=[[]]*a
for i in range(a):
for j in range(b):
ele=math.pow((i+j+1),-1)
li[i].append(ele)
return li
hilmat(a,b)
```

Comment: `invalid literal for int()` と表示されています。つまり、入力した文字列に `0-9` 以外の文字がある、ということになります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。つまりa = int(input("Enter row"))
b = int(input("Enter column"))の部分が違うということですよね。行、列ともに３の行列を作りたい場合、inputの()の中を3と入力しても同じエラーが出てしまいます。どのようにすればよろしいですかね。

Comment: 手元の環境(Python 3.10.4)で実行すると問題は発生しません。ただ、`li=[[]]*a` の部分は shallow copy になっていますので、想定される結果は得られないでしょう。

Comment: 知識不足ですみません。どのように変更したらいいのかわからないです。教えていただいてもよろしいですか。

Comment: `a = int(input("Enter row"))` と `b = int(input("Enter column"))` の部分は変更の必要はありません。そちらでエラーが発生しているとすれば、考えられる原因は「数字以外の文字を入力している」です。それ以外に原因があるとしても私には分かりません。以上です。