# Python　ヒルベルト行列　LU分解

Tags: python

後述の問題に対する (回答となる) プログラムがわからなくて困っています。

自分では以下のようにプログラムを書いてみましたが、 エラーが表示されてしまいます。
どのように変更したらうまく動くようになりますでしょうか。
いろいろ自分なりに調べて書いたので見当違いかもしれないですがよろしくお願いします。

ひとまず `a`, `b` の値は 5 で計算したいです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\autosave\untitled4.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = int(input("Enter row"))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**現状のプログラム:**

```
import math
a = int(input("Enter row"))
b = int(input("Enter column"))
def hilmat(a,b):
    li=[[]]*a
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(b):
            ele=math.pow((i+j+1),-1)
            li[i].append(ele)
    return li
hilmat(a,b)
```

**問題文:**

[image: 問題文です]

Comment: [tag:python] はタブによってブロックを区切る言語なので、コードブロックを使わずにプログラムを書かれると読めなくなってしまいます。コードブロックを使うように質問本文を編集していただくとよさそうです。

Comment: エラーが出るのはどの行ですか？エラー全文を掲載いただいた方が回答者にとって分かりやすくなります。
aとbの値についても追記してください。

Comment: エラー、a,bの値ともに記載させていただきました。

Comment: (スクリプトにミスもあるが) **発生してるエラー**に関しては [以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89947/) と同じで,
原因は(コメントの指摘にあるように)入力内容に数字以外がある, ということ。
スクリプトをどのように実行し, 何が表示され, それに対し何を入力したのか … を明確にしてください。(端折らずに)

Comment: 「input("Enter row")」のところで何を入力していますか？

Comment: 表示されているエラーメッセージ内容からすると、最初の入力時に何も入力せずにリターンキーを押下しただけの状態に見えます。何か操作方法とか手順を間違えているのでは？ 例えばフォルダ名からすると`spyder`というIDEを使っているようですが、それの環境設定とか使い方を間違えているとか？ そういった環境面も含めてどんな状況で何を操作して何処にどんな表示がされたかを追記してみてください。